# Is there any app available for reading the books downloaded in PDF format?

Tags: ebook-readers, pdf, apps

I like to listen to audiobooks a lot. Is there application which can read the downloaded books directly? There are various app but you have to manually copy the paragraphs and then it reads for you. It would be good to have app which can complete the whole book at a go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [best e-reader for pdfs](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/8214/best-e-reader-for-pdfs)

Comment: There is not a proper answer. And I have searched and tried various apps but it didn't work out.